# Create link between two existing files

Tags: command-line, symlink, hard-link

For example: I have file `a.txt` and file `b.txt`. I want a link from `a.txt` to `b.txt`. If I open/read file `a.txt`, file `b.txt` should open/read. If I try something like `ln -s a.txt b.txt` I get an error because file `b.txt` exist. How can I create a link from `a.txt` to `b.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove file `b.txt` previously with command `rm b.txt`, then create symbolic link with your command `ln -s a.txt b.txt`.

You could use hard link from `b.txt` to `a.txt`, then execute `ln a.txt b.txt`, both `a.txt` and `b.txt` would point the same file on hard drive and removing `a.txt` doesn't remove file, which could be read through `b.txt`.  With symbolic link from `b.txt` to `a.txt` removing `a.txt` remove file and `b.txt` symbolic link will be broken.  More about hard links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link

Comment: thanks, can you give me an example?

Comment: Example of **what**?

Answer (score 2):

Always check the man pages for help first. It'll save you a lot of time. Or if you're really busy, an `ln --help` at the shell gives

```
Usage: ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form) ....
```

Further down the help text, we find

```
...
-s, --symbolic  make symbolic links instead of hard links
-f, --force     remove existing destination files
...
```

which in a sense means, if you want to create a link for a file called `my_secret.file` as `my_secret.link`, you'll issue a command like

```
ln -sf my_secret.file my_secret.link
```

and if you do an `ls -l my_secret.link` in here. You'll get something like this

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 foouser groupbar  7 Jul 13 17:17 my_secret.link -> my_secret.file
```

The "l" in `lrwxrwxrwx` tells us that its a link.

Edit : Rahul struck first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-f` option, it removes existing destination files, if any, before creating the link.

```
ln -sf a.txt b.txt
```

found in `man ln` :

```
[OPTION] 
-f, --force
          remove existing destination files
```